# How to deploy basic python functions (with packages) on Google Cloud Functions

Tags: python-3.x, http, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am attempting to deploy a basic python function which calls an api using an HTTP trigger through Google Functions (browser-editor).

Here's the function I'm trying to deploy:

```
import requests
import json

def call_api():

    API_URL = 'https://some-api.com/v1'
    API_TOKEN = 'some-api-token'

    result = requests.get(API_URL+"/contacts?access_token="+API_TOKEN).json()
    print(result)

call_api()
```

My requirements.txt contains:

```
requests==2.21.0
```

However, every time I try to deploy the function, the following error occurs:

```
Unknown resource type
```

What am I doing wrong? The function works just fine on my local machine.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to [Writing HTTP Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#writing_http_helloworld-python) for more information. This is what comes to my mind when looking at your code:

- Missing the `request` parameter (`def call_api(request):`)
- Missing return at the end (you don't need to print it, just return it to the caller)
- Calling `call_api()` at the end of the file will call the function only locally, CFs don't need this

Make sure you are deploying using `gcloud functions deploy call_api --runtime python37 --trigger-http`